# Types for getter function with default value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this method that is supposed to fetch something using async and return the value, but if the value does not exist it should return a default value

```
async get(key: string, def_value?: any): Promise<any> {
   const v = await redisInstance.get(key);

   return v ? v : def_value;
}
```

Is it possible to add proper types to it, instead of any?

I was thinking of something like this:

```
async get<T>(key: string, def_value?: T): Promise<T>
```

Then it would infer type from def_value, but then def_value cannot be optional :(
Is there a way to have `def_value` both optional (undefined) and T, and have TS somehow detect if default value was passed or not? If it was passed - infer T from default_value, otherwise if it's not passed - to ask for a type, like `get<string[]>("my_key");` ?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwCYEsIElJQIZmAmAXhgG8AoGGAcwSgC4YAKAOleziogdwE8BKIgD4YAchEAaMgF8A3GTLYIPPDABmAVzxQU4arQA8ANXEwAKoMYUYAawQ8G0OCjBVJlJAlUB9AG7YANuoIAPwMppJ8DAAKcCAAtmgIRjAAPmapMJoeqs7IwuSUoFgwPkRM2ADu2CiwiKgYWLj4zDRQjLb8AoowhnJWiFDqcGAlMMHBMNm+AUFyUmRAA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Your code is actually working, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface Mapping {
  foo: 'bar'
}

declare const redisInstance: { get(key: any): any }

1) with mapping (if your key list is static)
async function get<K extends keyof Mapping>(key: K, def?: Mapping[K]): Promise<Mapping[K]> {
  return (await redisInstance.get(key) as Mapping[K]) ?? def;
}

get('foo')
get('foo', 'bar')
// function get<"foo">(key: "foo", def?: "bar" | undefined): Promise<"bar">

// 2) with overload: 
async function get1<T>(key: string, def: T): Promise<T>;
async function get1<T>(key: unknown extends T ? ['must have generic'] : string): Promise<T | undefined>;
async function get1<T>(key: any, def?: T): Promise<T | undefined> {
  return (await redisInstance.get(key) as T) ?? def;
}

get1('foo') // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '["must have generic"]'.(2345)
get1<string[]>('foo')
get1('foo', ['bar']) // Promise<string[]>
```